# bind property in dom's style attribute angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-style

I have problem with IE only when I try to render a property into style attribute.

**Html:**

```
<span style="background-color: {{ color }}">{{ color }}</span>
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.color = '#00ffff'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <span style="background:{{color}}">Hello, {{name}}!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rg6r35sq/1/)

If your solution will be using ngStyle I will be glad to example of code that use the variable `$scope.color`. That's mean that when the `$scope.color` will be change I want that the background will change too.

Comment: When you say IE please also post the version.

Comment: I was checked at 11 version, but I think that is not depends on version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ngStyle`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle#usage) directive:

```
<span ng-style="{'background-color': color}">Hello, {{name}}!</span>
```

Where `color` is your `$scope.color`

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
ng-style="{'background': (color)}"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rg6r35sq/3/